# Как закрыть или удалить учетную запись?

Tags: поддержка

Мне надоело. Как закрыть учетную запись?

Comment: Я думаю, можно попросту удалить всю личную информацию и больше не заходить. :) Хотя не могу понять, что может надоесть, если вы не будете просто заходить? Я, к примеру, целый год не заходил и нормально жил, пока не понадобилось вернуться по работе. :)

Comment: Незнаю почему но мне автоматическая идентификация только по куке не нравится, у меня несколько рабочих мест а прекратить сессию невозможно.

Comment: Простите, я вас немного не понял - как это невозможно выйти? А это что? Смотрите [скриншот](http://ssmaker.ru/e18969da/)

Comment: Спасибо, я эту маленькую кнопочку не заметил. Обычно это большая кнопка в правом верхнем углу.  Подожду с удаленем, теперь.

Comment: Не за что. Я в своё время тоже долго искал эту кнопочку. XD